# django rest permission called many times

Tags: django-rest-framework

So I'm building a simple blog app and made custom permission so only owner of post can update or delete the post, so I added print statment to check if it's working but found out it's called 6 times every time calling the view!
here's the code

```
class PostUpdateDeletePermission(IsAuthenticated):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("called")
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True
        if (request.method == 'PUT' or request.method == 'DELETE') and request.user != obj.user:
            return False
        return True

class PostView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (PostUpdateDeletePermission,)

    def create(self, request): 
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        obj = serializer.save(user=request.user)
        if request.data.get('files_length'):
            PostFile.objects.bulk_create([PostFile(img = request.data.get(f"file-{x}"), post=obj) for x in range(request.data.get('files_length'))])
        return Response({'posts' : serializer.data}, status=201)
```

that's how many times called printed when refreshing the drf browsable api

```
called
called
called
called
called
called
```

Comment: Try inheriting from BasePermission